# play audio when arrow buttons are pressed with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

ok im trying to write a code for an easter egg where different cat sounds go off when a different arrow button is pushed while on a page.

```
            <source src="catup_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>



     document.onkeydown = checkKey;
     function checkKey(e) {
     var catup=document.getElementById("myaudio")

     e = e || window.event;
 
     if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          catup.play() //up arrow
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
          catdown.play() // down arrow
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
          catleft.play() // left arrow
     }
     else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
          catright.play() // right arrow
     }
 
    }
```

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: ı think you need to use event listener to handle this. Check the [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) event on MDN.

Comment: and how does the relevant html look? do you have an error in console when you keydown up? and when you keydown down/left/right?